# How to use Material UI "Progress Indicator" between two set dates?

Tags: reactjs, date, material-ui, progress-bar

I am trying to add a feature in my website where there is a progress bar between two set dates (24 hours apart) and am struggling to find a package that provides this. I have been using Material UI to create other parts of the site and would hope for this to be possible with this [component](https://material-ui.com/components/progress/) I found.

I am thinking it would make sense to use the "linear determinate" option whose code is depicted below, but wonder how to modify it from lasting 500 ms to it lasting 24 hours after a given set start point.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import LinearProgress from '@material-ui/core/LinearProgress';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
});

export default function LinearDeterminate() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [progress, setProgress] = React.useState(0);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress((oldProgress) => {
        if (oldProgress === 100) {
          return 0;
        }
        const diff = Math.random() * 10;
        return Math.min(oldProgress + diff, 100);
      });
    }, 500);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={progress} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Would appreciate any general suggestions/modifications made to the code above! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out! Turns out it was pretty simple, all I had to was call a function that did the calculation for how much time was left within a given time frame and pass it in as the "value" for the LinearProgress component, see code below:

```
getProgressValue = (event, issue_date) => {
   let rightNow = new Date();
        
   let timePassed = rightNow - new Date(issue_date);
   let msInADay = 1000*60*60*24;
   let toReturn = (timePassed/msInADay) * 100;
   return toReturn;
}
```

```
<LinearProgress
   className="linearProgressMarginTop"
   variant="determinate"
   value={this.getProgressValue(event, req.issue_date)}
/>
```